# C++ #if #elif #endif don't seem to work

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

#define myvar B

#if myvar == A
        cout << "A" << endl;
#elif myvar == B
        cout << "B" << endl;
#else
        cout << "Neither" << endl;
#endif
}
```

The output is A but obviously I was expecting B

Comment: Does this toggle debug output?

Comment: No, it's just a contrived example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```
#if myvar == A
```

expands to:

```
#if B == A
```

Quoting the C++ standard:

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the **defined** unary
>   operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords,
>   except for **true** and **false**, are replaced with the pp-number **0**, and then
>   each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

so that's equivalent to:

```
#if 0 == 0
```

which is of course true.

The `==` operator in preprocessor expressions doesn't compare strings or identifiers, it only compares integer expressions. You can do what you're trying to do by defining integer values for `A`, `B`, and `myvar`, for example:

```
#define A 1
#define B 2
#define myvar B

#if myvar == A
    cout << "A" << endl;
#elif myvar == B
    cout << "B" << endl;
#else
    cout << "Neither" << endl;
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks - do you know how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me where to find a copy of the C++ standard? i.e. teach me to fish :)

Comment: @rmp251: You can get a draft of the C++ standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf). You can buy a copy of the official standard from ANSI or your national standards body. See also the ISO committee's [home page](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int main(void) {
    #define myvar 2
    #if myvar == 1
            std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    #elif myvar == 2
            std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    #else
            std::cout << "Neither" << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

More details please refer to the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx